# Averiguar el ultimo dia del mes segun una fecha en R

Tags: r

Tengo unos datos de fechas, necesito agregar una columna con la fecha del ultimo dia del mes.

Ejemplo

| Fecha | NuevaFecha |
| --- | --- |
| 02-02-2022 | 28-02-2022 |
| 14-02-2022 | 28-02-2022 |
| 25-02-2022 | 28-02-2022 |
| 01-03-2022 | 31-03-2022 |
| 12-03-2022 | 31-03-2022 |
| 26-03-2022 | 31-03-2022 |

Si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradezco.

Answer (score 3):

En cuanto a tratamiento de fechas, lo más cómodo es importar `lubridate` y para conocer puntualmente el último día del mes dada una fecha, puedes usar [`ceiling_date()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/0.2.3/topics/ceiling_date)

```
library(lubridate)

ceiling_date(as.Date("2022-03-23"), "month") - 1
[1] "2022-03-31"

# Considera el tema de los bisisetos
ceiling_date(as.Date("2020-02-23"), "month") - 1
[1] "2020-02-29"
```

¿Se puede resolver con código R puro? Si, es un pco más complejo, hay un articulo que trata este requerimiento: [Find the last day of the month](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/10/find-the-last-day-of-the-month/)